# Transpose and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

There is a question in Hoffman Kunze, $V$ finite dimensional, $T$ a linear operator with $\alpha$ non zero such that $T\alpha=c\alpha$ for some $c$. The question is to show that there is $f$ is the dual nonz ero such that $T^tf=cf$, where $T^t$ denotes the transpose.\

My attempt: I took $\alpha$ an extend it to a basis, say $\alpha,e_2,...,e_n$ and then took the dual base $f,f_2,...,f_n$. I think my $f$ should work but Im a bit confused. Because now, for $x\in V$, $x=f(x)\alpha+\sum f_i(x)e_i$, hence:
$$T^tf=(f\circ T)(x)= f\left(f(x)T\alpha+\sum f_i(x)Te_i\right)$$
$$=f\left(f(x)c\alpha+\sum f_i(x)Te_i\right)=cf(x)+\sum f_i(x)f(Te_i)$$
I dont know how to get rid of the terms $Te_i$. Can someone help me fix my proof? Or should I go other direction?

Comment: It might be easier to show that $\ker A$ is non trivial **iff** $\ker A^T$ is non trivial. (With $A=T-cI$.)

Comment: Got it man. Thanks!